What Apache setting or module is automatically "fixing" my html output, changing single to double quotes and http to https in links?
On a server with Apache 2.4 I have several virtual hosts for several domains.
On one of them, when serving static html files, links such as <a href='http://google.com'> get automatically "fixed" and rewritten to look like <a href="https://google.com">. Note that the single quotes have been replaced with double quotes and http has been rewritten as https in the url.
However, on another virtual host on the same machine, using the same Apache server, with apparently identical configuration, this doesn't happen.
The same happens to the output of PHP scripts, which is why I tested static html files to make sure that this was something about Apache and PHP has nothing to do with it.
I have diff-ed the two .htaccess files, and the configurations for the two virtual hosts, and can't find any difference. The list of enabled apache mods (as shown by phpinfo) is the same on both.
Obviously there must be some difference between the virtual hosts that I'm not spotting.
Are there any Apache directives, settings, or modules that do this kind of processing of the output?

It turns out it was CloudFlare, not Apache on my server. 
When you turn on SSL in CloudFlare, there's a setting called "Automatic HTTPS Rewrites" (quite difficult to find, under "Edge Certificates" for some reason), which

helps fix mixed content by changing “http” to “https” for all
resources or links on your web site that can be served with HTTPS

and apparently, while at it, it also fixes the single quotes.
